# Combine change and onload events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have coded this where I add / delete classes when you select from the form.
However if i choose as default select the 2nd select e.g.

```
<option value="7" selected>destination2</option>
```

then it doesn't change the class to `has-warning`. It changes only when I select the other and then this..

How can I add this feature? I tried this `$('#destination').onload(function() {` but there isn't such an event...

```js
$('#destination').change(function() {
   var dest = $('#destination').find(":selected").text();
   
   if (dest === 'destination1') {
       console.log('here1');
       $('#destin').removeClass("has-warning");
       $('#destin').addClass("has-success");
   
   } else if (dest === 'destination2') {
       console.log('here2');
       $('#destin').removeClass("has-success");
       $('#destin').addClass("has-warning");
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="destin" class="form-group has-success">
  <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Destination:</label>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <select id="destination" name="destination" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="1">destination1</option>
      <option value="7" selected>destination2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do it on page load. If you control where your `script` tags go, you just do it in immediately-run code in your script. If you don't control where `script` tags go, put it in a `ready` handler.

Here's that first option:

```js
function setDestinationWarningFlags() {
  var dest = $('#destination').find(":selected").text();

  if (dest === 'destination1') {
    console.log('here1');
    $('#destin').removeClass("has-warning");
    $('#destin').addClass("has-success");
  } else if (dest === 'destination2') {
    console.log('here2');
    $('#destin').removeClass("has-success");
    $('#destin').addClass("has-warning");
  }
}
// Do it on change:
$('#destination').change(setDestinationWarningFlags);
// Initial setup:
setDestinationWarningFlags();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="destin" class="form-group has-success">
  <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Destination:</label>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <select id="destination" name="destination" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="1">destination1</option>
      <option value="7" selected>destination2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have to use a ready callback instead, just change the last bit from:

```
// Initial setup:
setDestinationWarningFlags();
```

to

```
// Initial setup:
$(setDestinationWarningFlags);
```

...which is a shortcut for [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready):

```js
function setDestinationWarningFlags() {
  var dest = $('#destination').find(":selected").text();

  if (dest === 'destination1') {
    console.log('here1');
    $('#destin').removeClass("has-warning");
    $('#destin').addClass("has-success");

  } else if (dest === 'destination2') {
    console.log('here2');
    $('#destin').removeClass("has-success");
    $('#destin').addClass("has-warning");
  }
}
// Do it on change:
$('#destination').change(setDestinationWarningFlags);
// Initial setup:
$(setDestinationWarningFlags);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="destin" class="form-group has-success">
  <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Destination:</label>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <select id="destination" name="destination" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="1">destination1</option>
      <option value="7" selected>destination2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export logic to a function and call this function on both `change` and `document.ready` event.

Also, if you have to `add/remove` classes, try to use `.toggleClass`

#### Sample

```js
$('#destination').change(function() {
  updateUIState();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  updateUIState();
})

function updateUIState() {
  var dest = $('#destination').find(":selected").text();
  var isDest2 = dest === 'destination2';
  $('#destin').toggleClass("has-warning", isDest2);
  $('#destin').toggleClass("has-success", isDest2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="destin" class="form-group has-success">
  <label for="inputName" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Destination:</label>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <select id="destination" name="destination" class="form-control" required>
      <option value="1">destination1</option>
      <option value="7" selected>destination2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#destination").trigger("change");
});
```

In order for your on change event handler to run when the page loads.

Comment: Better to move the functionality to a reusable function, rather than synthetically firing the event.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't object to that, it is better for the functionality to be in reusable functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/) for an initial trigger, just append it to your chain:

```
$('#destination').change(function() {
   var dest = $('#destination').find(":selected").text();

   if (dest === 'destination1') {
       console.log('here1');
       $('#destin').removeClass("has-warning");
       $('#destin').addClass("has-success");

   } else if (dest === 'destination2') {
       console.log('here2');
       $('#destin').removeClass("has-success");
       $('#destin').addClass("has-warning");
   }
 }).triggerHandler("change");
```